# solution of $y^{\prime \prime} + y^n = 1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems, calculus-of-variations

I am not able to figure out the solution for the differential solution
$$y^{\prime \prime} + y^n = 1$$
I want to specifically find an answer for $$y^{\prime \prime} + y^2= 1$$and $$y^{\prime \prime} + y^3 = 1$$

If anyone can help!

Comment: Have you any reason to think that closed form exist ?

Comment: I don't think there is a nice solution to this in general unfortunately :/ best you might be able to do for an analytic solution is a series solution but that would get really nasty really fast because of the nonlinearity.

Comment: I do not understand why it is asked to improve the question. There is no need for additional context to solve it. There is no need to have an answer to the question  "where you have difficulties ?" . Everybody trying to solve the equation immediately can answer itself by his own experience and see where is the difficulty.  Such a request appears as formal attitude in the present case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y''+y^n=1$$
An obvious solution is $y=1$. Apart this trivial case :
$$2y''y'+2y^ny'=2y'$$
$$(y')^2+\frac{2}{n+1}y^{n+1}=2y+c_1$$
$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm\sqrt{2y+c_1-\frac{2}{n+1}y^{n+1}}$$
$$x=\pm\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2y+c_1-\frac{2}{n+1}y^{n+1}}}+c_2$$
$x(y)$ is the inverse function of $y(x)$.

There is no general closed form for the integral and even more for the inverse function.

Further calculus supposes to analytically solve a polynomial equation of $(n+1)$ degree. Theoretically it is possible up to $n+1=4$. So, the closed form   exists for $n=2$ and $n=3$ not for $n>3$.

In fact, the main difficulty comes from the analytical solving of the polynomial equation, which roots involve huge formulas. If we suppose that the roots are known, further calculs involves elliptic integral of the first kind to express $x(y)$, then Jacobi amplitude function to express y(x) :

[image]

[image]

Comment: for $n=2,$ interesting mixture of behaviors (taking $y'(0) = 0$), some periodic, one asymptotic to $y=-1,$ $y=1$ stable and $y=-1$ not, otherwise solutions got to $-\infty$ in finite positive time and finite negative time. $n=3,$ all periodic. Phase portraits are interesting, $x_1 = y, x_2 = y'$

Comment: for $n=2$ we find $V = 2 y^3 - 6 y + 3 (y')^2$ is constant.

Comment: With $y'(0) = 0:$ if $y(0) = 2,$ we get a bell curve, otherwise constant or periodic or unbounded (going to $- \infty$ in finite time).

Comment: In particular, there are two solutions (up to translation) that never have $y'=0,$ that satisfy $2 y^3 - 6y + 3 (y')^2 = 4$ and are asymptotic to $y=-1$ but with $y < -1.$